# Opened documents not showing up right away in taskbar recent jumplist

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2021

One of the Word upgrades caused opened documents to not show up in the taskbar Jumplist recent documents list right away. At one time just opening the document would make it appear right away. Now it seems like you have to save changes to get it to show up.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I get opened documents to to show up right away in the Word  taskbar recent documents jumplist again?